# Python Generating new Column from conditional of two values in the same row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and still learning pandas. I'm hoping I can get some help.

**What I've Done**

- Merging two datasets in to one data frame

**What I'm trying to do**

- Generate new column
- The values in the new column will be based on 4 conditionals of two values in the same row

**Sample Data**

This the merged data

```
>>> rctf
       CompName         Tevent_id  event_id   
0      Server1                0.0       NaN
1      Server2               16.0      16.0
2      Server3               16.0       2.0
3      Server4                3.0       3.0
4      Server5                3.0       NaN
5      Server6                2.0       2.0
```

**Expected Output**

```
    CompName         Tevent_id      event_id   status
0      Server1                0.0       NaN    T Only
1      Server2               16.0      16.0    Match
2      Server3               16.0       2.0    No Match
3      Server4                3.0       3.0    Match
4      Server5                3.0       NaN    T Only
5      Server6                2.0       2.0    Match
6      Server7                NaN       2.0    W Only
```

**What I've tried**
I found the link below and it's basically what I want to do but I'm doing mutliple conditionals.

https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_create_column_using_conditional/

I've been looking at the .where method and haven't really figured it out yet.

**The Conditionals**

- if Tevent_id and event_id both exist and match "Match"
- if Tevent_id and event_id both exist and don't match "No Match"
- if TeventId exist and event_id doesn't "T Only"
- if TeventId doesn't exist and event_id does "W Only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use lambda:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def isNaN(num):
    return num != num


e = {
    'CompName': ['Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3', 'Server4', 'Server5', 'Server6', 'Server7'],
    'Tevent_id': [0.0, 16.0, 16.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, np.nan],
    'event_id': [ np.nan, 16.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 2.0, 2.0]
}

c_table = pd.DataFrame(data=e)

c_table['status'] = None


def process_row(row):
    if (row['Tevent_id'] == row['event_id']):
        return "Match"
    elif (isNaN(row['Tevent_id']) and not isNaN(row['event_id'])):
        return "W Only"
    elif (not isNaN(row['Tevent_id']) and isNaN(row['event_id'])):
        return "T Only"
    elif (not isNaN(row['Tevent_id']) and not isNaN(row['event_id'])):
        return "No Match"
    else:
        return "Both NaN"

c_table['status'] = c_table.apply(lambda row: process_row(row), axis=1)

print( c_table)
```

the result:

```
  CompName  Tevent_id  event_id    status
0  Server1        0.0       NaN    T Only
1  Server2       16.0      16.0     Match
2  Server3       16.0       2.0  No Match
3  Server4        3.0       3.0     Match
4  Server5        3.0       NaN    T Only
5  Server6        2.0       2.0     Match
6  Server7        NaN       2.0    W Only
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with isNan          

                                                      
NameError: ("name 'isNaN' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

Write a function like the following:

```
def GetNewColumn(row):

    if row['Tevent_id'] ==  row['event_id']:
        val = 'Match'
    elif ......

    else:

    return val

df['Status'] = df.apply(GetNewColumn, axis=1)
```